# Apache Beam Min, Max and Average

Tags: python, apache-beam

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756539/max-and-min-for-several-fields-inside-pcollection-in-apache-beam-with-python), Guillem Xercavins wrote a custom class for compute minimum and maximum.

```
class MinMaxFn(beam.CombineFn):
  # initialize min and max values (I assumed int type)
  def create_accumulator(self):
    return (sys.maxint, 0)

  # update if current value is a new min or max
  def add_input(self, min_max, input):
    (current_min, current_max) = min_max
    return min(current_min, input), max(current_max, input)

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
    return accumulators

  def extract_output(self, min_max):
    return min_max
```

I need to compute average as well, and I found sample code as below:

```
class MeanCombineFn(beam.CombineFn):
  def create_accumulator(self):
    """Create a "local" accumulator to track sum and count."""
    return (0, 0)

  def add_input(self, (sum_, count), input):
    """Process the incoming value."""
    return sum_ + input, count + 1

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
    """Merge several accumulators into a single one."""
    sums, counts = zip(*accumulators)
    return sum(sums), sum(counts)

  def extract_output(self, (sum_, count)):
    """Compute the mean average."""
    if count == 0:
      return float('NaN')
    return sum_ / float(count)
```

Any idea how to merge the average method into MinMax so I can have only one class that able to compute Minimum, Maximum and Average all together and produce a set of key and values- array of 3 values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the combined class solution, with addition of median

```
import numpy as np

class MinMaxMeanFn(beam.CombineFn):

    def create_accumulator(self):
        # sum, min, max, count, median
        return (0.0, 999999999.0, 0.0, 0, [])

    def add_input(self, cur_data, input):
        (cur_sum, cur_min, cur_max, count, cur_median) = cur_data
        if type(input) == list:
            cur_count = len(input)
            sum_input = sum(input)
            min_input = min(input)
            max_input = max(input)
        else:
            sum_input = input
            cur_count = 1
        return cur_sum + sum_input, min(min_input, cur_min), max(max_input, cur_max), count + cur_count, cur_median + input

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        sums, mins, maxs, counts, medians = zip(*accumulators)
        return sum(sums), min(mins), max(maxs), sum(counts), medians

    def extract_output(self, cur_data):
        (sum, min, max, count, medians) = cur_data
        avg = sum / count if count else float('NaN')
        med = np.median(medians)
        return  {
            "max": max,
            "min": min,
            "avg": avg,
            "count": count,
            "median": med
        }
```

Example usage:

```
( input |'Format Price' >> beam.ParDo(FormatPriceDoFn())
                        |'Group Price by ID' >> beam.GroupByKey()
                        |'Compute price statistic for each ID' >> beam.CombinePerKey(MinMaxMeanFn()))
```

*I did not test if CombinePerKey works without GroupByKey, feel free to test it out.

Comment: Can you please share the example usage of MinMaxMeanFn?
Let's say I first create a pipeline using `beam.Create([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`. How do I call the MinMaxMeanFn method on this PCollection?

Comment: hi @xennygrimmato I have updated the code since I posted the solution. For the usage, u basically have a pardo to format the pcollection into key and value. Then you can combine them either by key or globally depends on your use case, and call this MinMaxMeanFn in the combine function -> beam.CombinePerKey(MinMaxMeanFn())